# How can I get a random cell in OpenOffice Calc?

Tags: formula, worksheet-function, openoffice-calc

I've perused the Stack Exchange list of sites, and I can only think that SO is the right place to ask this (I saw a few excel questions, at least).

I have an array of values `Sheet1.B3:B9`.  On another sheet, I'm trying to get a random value from one of those cells.

I suppose it has to be something with the `RANK()` function, but I'm grasping at straws.

How can I get the value of a random cell in that range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Excel, this will give random lookup into the range

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$3:$B$9,INT(RAND()*7)+1)
```

Or you can give your source data range a name

```
=INDEX(RandDataSource,INT(RAND()*ROWS(RandDataSource))+1)
```

Don't know if it applies to Openoffice

Comment: Pointing me tyo index allowed me to find this http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Calc_Guide/Address,_Indirect,_Offset,_Index#INDEX_returns_cells_inside_a_specified_range  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 7):

In LibreOffice Calc to get a random cell between cells B3 and B9 of Sheet1 you can do:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1.B3:B9, RANDBETWEEN(1,5))
```